# Sonos API Extendedmetadata probleem

Tags: sonos

I'm having problems with the Sonos api for Extendedmetadata, please see below output. The art and extra information is not shown for track info.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
          <getExtendedMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <getExtendedMetadataResult>
              <mediaMetadata>
                <id>track-28938</id>
                <itemType>track</itemType>
                <mimeType>audio/mp3</mimeType>
                <trackMetadata>
                  <artistId>artist-4619</artistId>
                  <artist>Jelte Veenhoven</artist>
                  <albumid>album-916</albumid>
                  <album>From Olivet to Calvary</album>
                  <duration>397</duration>
                  <albumArtURI>http://<server ip>/functions/load_albumart.php?album_id=916&amp;size=200</albumArtURI>
                  <canSkip>true</canSkip>
                  <canAddToFavorites>true</canAddToFavorites>
                </trackMetadata>
              </mediaMetadata>
            </getExtendedMetadataResult>
          </getExtendedMetadataResponse>
        </soap:Body>
      </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I missed the title tag in mediaMetadata, which was not mentioned in any Sonos examples and Manuals.....

:-)

Answer (score 0):

First, trackMetadata doesn't have any Extra field. Check http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/83 for detailed information. 
Second, what do you mean by art information?
Keep in mind that non-mandatory fields specified in the wsdl file that are not generated in your python/php code won't appear in the SOAP response.
You need to provide more information about your code. We can't just guess.

Comment: What extra information do you need? For some reason I just cant find the problem in my XML as the Sonos device is only requesting the extra metadata. In the reference I noticed the capital chars are required the tags but in the manuals the tags names differ on different locations in the reference docs.